# How to create a grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, backend

I need to create a simple grid in admin section, which contains all orders filtered by customer's email. I can't figure it out how I can fill the grid with custom data. All the examples found online create a custom table and then populate the grid with the data retrieved by that table. I don't need it. I just want to get all orders filtered by customer's email as I mentioned before.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you got answer ?how can I connect the grid with my custom collection? below answer is not fully this requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that it is not as simple that follow a tutorial but I recommend you to check the Magento 2 CMS core module.

You will see how Magento creates CMS block and pages grid.

Then copy/paste and adapt the impacted files to follow your needs.

You will learn more features this way and become more independent.

This is a non exhaustive list of useful files :

- vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_block_listing.xml
- vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_block_form.xml
- vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/layout/cms_block_edit.xml
- vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/layout/cms_block_index.xml
- vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/layout/cms_block_new.xml
- vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/templates/page/edit/form/renderer/content.phtml
- vendor/magento/module-cms/Block/Adminhtml/Page/Grid/Renderer/Action/UrlBuilder.php
- vendor/magento/module-cms/Block/Adminhtml/Block/Edit/*.php
- vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Block/*.php
- vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/Block/DataProvider.php
- vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/Block/Source/IsActive.php
- vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/ResourceModel/Block/Grid/Collection.php
- vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/ResourceModel/Block/Relation/Store/ReadHandler.php
- vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/ResourceModel/Block/Relation/Store/SaveHandler.php
- **vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml**

I hope it will be useful for you.

In order to populate the grid data, create your custom Grid Collection as Datasource or reuse the order grid collection.

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="cms_page_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page\Grid\Collection</item>
            <item name="cms_block_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">cms_block</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">cms_block_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">block_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

For orders in `vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/di.xml:799`

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sales_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
            <item name="sales_order_invoice_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Grid\Collection</item>
            <item name="sales_order_shipment_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Grid\Collection</item>
            <item name="sales_order_creditmemo_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Creditmemo\Grid\Collection</item>
            <item name="sales_order_view_invoice_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Orders\Grid\Collection</item>
            <item name="sales_order_view_shipment_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
            <item name="sales_order_view_creditmemo_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Creditmemo\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Feel free to ask some extra details.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had your same idea (check the core) and I found a solution for what I was looking for. Basically I was declaring my data source in a wrong way, I had to extend this class 
`\Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult`

Answer (score 0):

please go thorough this link its helpfull to create grid https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. I've already seen this guide but I can't figure it out how he retrieves the data from the table. Anyway, how can I connect the grid with my custom collection?